# CSS on resize scrollbars

Tags: html, css

It's me again with a very small question! I make two divs, one containing another and the second one having some text on the left and an image on the right. Code works good but by the time I resize it I notice that the text form lines to fit the image.. Is there a way for this not to happen, for no resize to be made but scrollbars to appear? I tried `resize: both;` on second div but it was the same result...

```css
div.div1 {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.div2 {
  background-color: #e2d8ba;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="http://www.dailyrecoverymeditations.com/forums/image.php?u=2057&dateline=1404850818" style="float:right; padding-left: 10px;"> 
    
    Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code works good but by the time I resize it I notice that the text form lines to fit the image.. Can you explain what does this sentence mean?

Comment: Run the code and resize the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a fixed width for  `div2` and define `overflow: auto` for both DIVs, then scrollbars will appear:

```css
div.div1 {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.div2 {
  background-color: #e2d8ba;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="http://www.dailyrecoverymeditations.com/forums/image.php?u=2057&dateline=1404850818" style="float:right; padding-left: 10px;"> Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this? If you want the text to be the element that cuts off and is scrollable you need to give it its own div and make that one `overflow: auto`.

```css
div.div1 {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.div2 {
  background-color: #e2d8ba;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.div3 {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="http://www.dailyrecoverymeditations.com/forums/image.php?u=2057&dateline=1404850818" style="float:right; padding-left: 10px;">
    <div class="div3">Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Um, not exactly. I mean, if I resize the window, the initial image to stay the exact same and scrollbars to appear...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap text text with `div` and give it fixed `witdth`. Then give it attribute `overflow: auto`

```css
div.div1 {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.div2 {
  background-color: #e2d8ba;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.div2 .text-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

div.div2 .text-wrapper .text {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="http://www.dailyrecoverymeditations.com/forums/image.php?u=2057&dateline=1404850818" style="float:right; padding-left: 10px;"> 
    
    <div class="text-wrapper">
     <div class="text">
       Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want the whole div2 to scroll then you give fixed with to `div2`